# Flutter - Getting data from firestore in a loop

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

So basically I have a collection a User and within each user there is a subcollection for the pending friend request that the user have, something like that:

/users/[auto-id]/friend_requests/[auto-id]/{user: ref to another user}

But one user can obviously have multiple requests at the same time and I have an hard time to get the data correctly.

What I'm correctly trying to do is to get a list of user that are in the subcollection "friend_requests":

```
_loadFriendRequests() async {
    try {
      this._users.addAll(await _dataService.fetchFriend());
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      printException(e, stackTrace, "Error loading friends");
    }
}
```

And in dataService:

```
Future<List<User>> fetchFriend() async {
    final querySnapshot =
        await _currentUserDoc.reference.collection("friend_requests").getDocuments();

    return await Future.wait(querySnapshot.documents.map((doc) async {
      final user = await doc["user"].get();
      User(
        id: user["id"],
        name: user["name"],
      );
    }).toList(growable: false));
  }
```

This is just the last thing that I tried but I tried in so many ways, with Future.wait() too, with/without async/await, etc
I just can't seem to make it work...

Comment: Maybe you could try a nested get like https://github.com/swat-cat/booker/blob/44ca9aa2ede23bb9a51535e39f6e16c30e308fda/lib/services/activities.dart#L28 I am not an expert, but this might help.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a return statement after `final user = await doc["user"].get();`

---

*This could become a lot easier if you use [Streams](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/streams) or fancy [rxdart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart)*